# Send variable to external PHP file from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code to include in one domain (`http://www.example1.com`)

```
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="http://www.example2.com/API/incoming.php?id=560">
</script>
```

All this does is invoke the page `incoming.php` in my second domain (`http://www.example2.com`), and send it the value "560".

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to send runtime variables to the page? (Eg : I am hard coding `560`, is there any way to get it dynamically if it is part of the URL?

   Would it be possible to send the page URL where this script was loaded? This is what I tried so far, but I am not able to access the variable URL.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example2.com/API/incoming.php?id=560">
var Url = "";
if (typeof this.href != "undefined") {
       Url = this.href.toString().toLowerCase(); 
}else{ 
       Url = document.location.toString().toLowerCase();
}
</script>
```

Comment: If any of this is unclear, I apologize. Please do let me know how I can clarify!

Comment: Are you trying to embed javascript resource dynamically?

Comment: Ah no, I embed the code at design time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create the script tag dynamically and pass all the variables you like via GET.

```
<script>
    (function() {
        var id = 560;
        var url = document.location.toString().toLowerCase(); // use other means if necessary

        var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
        scriptElement.src = 'your.php?id=' + encodeURI(id) + '&url=' + encodeURI(url);
        document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
    }());
</script>
```

the `scriptElement` will begin to load after it is inserted in the document.

this is how google analytics and others did or do it.

Comment: I need to embed this into a HTML page, can I just put the whole thing into a `Javascript` block?

Comment: Ok I just want to confirm one thing. Will the above code (if put on `www.example.com` ) be equivalent to the following?

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example2.com/your.php?id=560&url=http://example.com"></script>`

Comment: yes. on modern browsers. i assume you are building with HTML5. i also assume you changed: `your.php` to `http://www.example2.com/your.php`. and you forgot the `www.` in the query. please keep in mind that the url will also contains the path. so it could be `www.example.com/info.html` on a subpage.

Comment: Just finished testing it! Works like a charm, thank you so much!

Comment: i edited the answer. and enclosed the code in an anonymous function. this way the snippet can not conflict with other code on your site, wich for example might also use an `id` variable.

Comment: Awesome! One last thing, is it also possible to track unique visits using this? (I am storing the incoming URL and IP address so far)

Comment: you can track visits by ip address this way. you could assume that a visit is unique if it comes from one ip and there has not been a visit from that ip for a while. for a better tracking you might want to use cookies. also: you do not need to send the url to the server manually. the browser does this automatically. in php it is accessed through `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]`